# When trying to download file from Commits Page on Azure DevOps it opens in a new tab in browser. From Files Page it downloads normally

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

After updating to latest Azure DevOps, when trying to download file from Commits Page, file opens in a new tab showing the code/script. From Files Page it downloads normally.

Any ideas what that's about? Checked with other colleagues, same deal, all browsers.

Comment: Probably a bug where Azure DevOps isn't sending the correct headers. ctrl-click should help.

Comment: You can report the bug here: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/search?space=21

Comment: PS: There is no "Team Foundation Server in Azure" unless your org installed an old versions of TFS on an azure VM. TFS has been renamed to Azure DevOps, the latest version is 2020.0.1 at the moment.

Comment: @jessehouwing ctrl_click opens in new tab, I want to download the file. Any other suggestions? Thanx

Comment: Don't think there is a keyboard shortcut to do that... At least I don't know it. That would be a wonderful question for superuser.com though. But not here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by disabling "New Repos Pull Request Experience" feature for my account from Preview Features on the top right.

Comment: That's great you fixed it by disable the preview feature. You can accept above answer of yours.

Comment: Just did. I've opened a bug on MS and the issue is fixed and will be deployed on next version of devops.